# How to add custom Transformer/Estimator in nyoka and convert a pipeline to PMML doc?

Tags: pmml

I am writing a Python scikit-learn pipeline which needs custom transformer/estimator (not the regular already defined transformers in sklearn) .

How can I add this support and convert the pipeline to PMML doc using skl_to_pmml (python nyoka lib)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Nyoka supports only sklearn's transformers. We shall implement custom transformers in near future based on our prioritized tasks.